# Timestamping in a post request body in Gatling Simulation

Tags: scala, gatling

The JSON body of the post request consists of a time parameter that needs to get changed wrt time.

How can I define an attribute for the same so that I can call it like this in the request body,

```
"time": "${timestamp}"
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a built-in Expression Language function `currentTimeMillis()`, see [doc](https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/expression_el/#expression-language).

Comment: I was able to make use of it for Simple Date Format, ${currentDate(<pattern>)}. What we can do if we have a pattern  <Wed, 31 Mar 2021>?